How can I use a lambda expression as constant primary expression in a requires clause?
I'm trying to understand different ways of specifying a C++ requires clause. I need some deeper understanding, not a technical solution for specifying a constraint.
Think of a template function:
template<typename T>
T func(T t) {
  return t;
}

A simple though useless requires clause could be added:
template<typename T>
requires true
T func(T t) {
  return t;
}

and I could call this function like so:
foo(1);

As far as I understand https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_clauses I could also use a constant lambda expression as a lambda expression is also a primary expression (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Primary_expressions).
template<typename T>
requires [] { return  true; }
T func(T t) {
  return t;
}

Using cl.exe from VS2019 / VS2022 I get a compile error similar to (translated):
error C7607: The atomic constraint has to be a constant expression of type Bool...
I tried using constexpr without any success.
What I do not want: requires ([] { return  true; }())

Uhh. It being a primary-expression is not the only requirement, it must be a compile-time boolean constant.

@HolyBlackCat: I understand this and thought I could make the lambda expression constexpr, but I didn't manage. This is why I asked this question - I'm really stuck.

A lambda expression is not a bool until you call it. You seem to know this (last paragraph of your question), so I don't understand why you thought you could get away with not calling it.

you provide a link, but it is unclear what exactly in here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_clauses made you conclude that your snippet would be ok

A lambda expression's type is a class type determined by the compiler. It doesn't matter what the lambda returns unless you actually invoke the lambda.
Class types are not boolean types. Since the standard requires that the expression in a requires clause be a constant expression of boolean type. You can make the lambda expression a constant expression, but you can't make it of boolean type.

I misinterpreted the description at XXX, and your response helped me, especially because you referred to the C++ standard. Thank you so much!
Also thank you to all the other commenters, I realized that I couldn't get my question to the point and that it must have been confusing. Sorry for that.


How can I use a lamda expression as constant primary expression in a requires clause?

By immediately invoking the lambda.
This is because [] { return  true; } is an object of some compiler specific type(aka closure type) but the requires-expression need to be a constant expression of type bool.
So in order to make this work, just call the lambda using the function call operator () with additional parenthesis around it. Demo
